# Call a public method of a WKInterfaceController from ExtensionDelegate class- WatchKit

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchos-2, wkinterfacecontroller

I am calling the

```
`[[WCSession defaultSession] updateApplicationContext:message error:error]`
```

method which is triggered in my

```
 `-(void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveApplicationContext:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)applicationContext`
```

method in `ExtensionDelegate`. But from here I want to call a public method in a `WKInterfaceController` to update my UI. I don't want to reload the root controllers as this particular controller is not the root controller. Is it possible to call any public method from `ExtensionDelegate`. Can I call

`-(void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveApplicationContext:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)applicationContext`

from somewhere within Interface controller instead of `ExtensionDelegate`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WCSession`'s

```
public func sendMessage(message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: (([String : AnyObject]) -> Void)?, errorHandler: ((NSError) -> Void)?)
```

this will invoke `WCSessionDelegate`'s

```
public func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void)
```

method in delegate class. This can be used from both app and extension for instantaneous message transfer. Read [more](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html)

Comment: Problem is I have to call update UI method based on timer. The updateApplicationContext method is called on timer invocation and this is called from my watchConnectivityManager. When this method is called, it triggers the corresponding recieveApplicationContext method present in ExtensionDelegate. What I want to know is can recieveApplicationContext method be called from within any interfaceController instead of ExtensionDelegate